# regex to match white space and one

Tags: regex

I am a beginner when it comes to writing a regular expression, I want o write regex which can match the following lines

```
 0 x0_0                            1                 -228900  Result - true
 0 x2_0                            0                 -228900  Result - false
 0 x3_0                            0                 -128900  Result - false
```

Actually I want regex to return true if it has

```
x<AnyDigit>_<AnyDigit> <WhiteSpace>  1
```

I have written below expression

```
x(\d+)_(\d+)[\s1]
```

but it is returning true in below case as well

```
0 x3_0                           0                 -128900
```

Comment: Try  `x\d+_\d+\s+1` https://regex101.com/r/VD4TGG/1 Or match a space or tab instead of `\s` `x\d+_\d+[ \t]+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[\s1]` is a character class that matches a single character that is either whitespace or the digit `1`.

In the line

```
0 x3_0                           0                 -128900
```

we have `x(\d+)_(\d+)[\s1]` (at the end of the regex) matching `x3_0`:

- `x` matches itself.
- the first `\d+` group matches `3`
- `_` matches itself
- the second `\d+` group matches `0`
- `[\s1]` matches the space after `0`

A literal regex translation of your requirements would be

```
x\d_\d\s+1
```

which matches `x`, followed by a digit, followed by `_`, followed by a digit, followed by one or more whitespace characters, followed by `1`.

Answer (score 2):

In  your pattern you use a character class `[\s1]` which will match either a whitespace char (which will also match a newline) or a 1.

If you want a match only, you can omit the capturing groups. Note that `\d+` matches 1+ digits.

You could update your pattern to:

```
\bx\d+_\d+[ \t]+1\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bx\d+` Match word boundary to prevent x being part of a larger word, then 1+ digits
- `_\d+` Match underscore followed by 1+ digits
- `[ \t]+` Match 1+ times a space or tab
- `1\b` Match 1 follower by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZXZmoj/1)